# Constraining Generic Type extensions with inheritance

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, extension-methods

I am trying to implement type safety for property list values.

I have defined an empty protocol `PropertyListValue` and have created extensions for the appropriate types.

```
protocol PropertyListValue {

}

extension Data: PropertyListValue {}
extension Date: PropertyListValue {}
extension String: PropertyListValue {}
extension Int: PropertyListValue {}
extension Double: PropertyListValue {}
extension Array: PropertyListValue where Element: PropertyListValue {}
extension Dictionary: PropertyListValue where Value: PropertyListValue {}
```

The problem is with the collection types. I get the error:

> Extension of type 'Array' with constraints cannot have an inheritance
>   clause

I have also tried using:

```
extension Array<PropertyListValue>: PropertyListValue {}
```

but I get the error:

> Constrained extension must be declared on the unspecialized generic
>   type 'Array' with constraints specified by a 'where' clause

How can I extend Array and Dictionary to conform to the protocol only when they contain types of the protocol?

Comment: You can't currently. The feature [is coming](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md) in a future version of Swift however.